# getResourceAsStream returns InputStream but Scanner is unable to read

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to load a text file from the root of my .jar file. I have tried something like this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/infobook.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
while(scan.hasNextLine())
{
    strings.add(scan.nextLine());
}
```

I do not get any runtime exceptions, however, no lines are added to the ArrayList. I then tried something like `System.out.println(scan.nextLine());` and I got a `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` exception. 
Now I am pretty stuck and need your help. The text file has 21 lines of text.
How would I go about loading this text file from the jar?

[edit]
I have also tried reading the input stream like this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/infobook.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

Giving the following error: `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths`

Comment: Have you tried to read something from `is` directly without `scan`?

Comment: I've just tried this: http://pastebin.com/KaQzHGLs and got this error: `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths`. I hope this is what you mean with "directly"

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question and getting me closer to the answer. I just updated my java and now the same code is working flawlessly. I don't really know why :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are viewing this in the future - 
If you are on OSX, try updating your java. That worked for me and may work for you too. Otherwise, do try the other answers below/above.

Answer (score 2):

I would check there is not a file in your classpath (one you don't expect) which is empty.  Try printing

```
// print where the file is found.
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/infobook.txt"));
```

Comment: This returns: `jar:file:/Users/notro/Documents/Developments/java/fileio.jar!/infobook.txt`. So I think the file exists :?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create similar scenario but all time I have runned successfully. But  even if you give wrong file name, It create different exception. I mean Scanner cannot read it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a character set problem; select this explicitly.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(is, "Windows-1252");
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work :(. I also tried "UTF-8", no success.

Comment: Maybe "UTF16LE"? But first look with 7zip or WinZip into the jar for /infobook.txt.